# How can I recreate a mediawiki database from scratch?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to completely drop an old instance of a MediaWiki and create a new one. I recreated the server side of things and dropped the database which was on AWS RDS.
Now I'm getting errors that X table is not present (at this moment it's an empty database).
Most questions of the sort out there say that one should use the update.php script, but that does not work on an empty database.
How can I create a fresh MediaWiki database (with no content)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use the PHP CLI to run the install script. To do this one needs to delete or move the file LocalSettings.php away first, then go to the directory where the MediaWiki was unpacked and run `php maintenance/install.php`.

The mandatory arguments are the name of the wiki and the name of the admin, but as I already had a database created elsewhere I added the relevant options:

`php maintenance/install.php --dbuser myuser --dbpass mypassword --dbname mydb --dbserver mydbserver.rds.amazonaws.com --with-extensions --pass myadminpassword mywiki myadmin`